# Log4net does not log to SQL Server 2008 R2 from VS studio 2010

Tags: sql, for-loop, sql-server-2008-r2, log4net

I am trying to Log to SQL Server using Log4net in a WCF Service.I am using Windows authentication and connection to db is fine.
Below are the config File and code.
The File Log is happening correctly.

```
    <configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
  </configSections>

 <log4net debug ="true">
    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender_SqlServer" />
        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>

    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <connectionString value="data source=V01KUMAVX\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=dbLog;integrated security=SSPI;" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%level" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="2000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
      </parameter>
    </appender>
</log4net>
</configuration>

and the code : 

    public class Service1 : IService1
        {
            private static readonly log4net.ILog log;

            static Service1()
            {
                log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

                log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

            }

            public string GetData(int value)
            {

                log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

                log.Debug(string.Format("You entered: {0}", value));

                if (!log4net.LogManager.GetRepository().Configured)
                {
                    // log4net not configured
                    foreach (log4net.Util.LogLog message in log4net.LogManager.GetRepository().ConfigurationMessages)
                    {
                        // evaluate configuration message
                    }
                }

                return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
            }
    }
```

How to Log the Log4net Silent errors and how to view them ?

Answer (score 2):

Your Appender names don't match:

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
```

vs.

```
<appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender_SqlServer" />
```

Change them both to be "AdoNetAppender" or "AdoNetAppender_SqlServer" so that they match (doesn't matter which).